# Using async_work_group_copy() with pointer?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

```c
__kernel void kmp(__global char pattern[1*4], __global char* string, 
                  __global int failure[1*4], __global int ret[1], 
                  int g_length, int l_length, int thread_num){
    int pattern_num = 1;
    int pattern_size = 4;
    int gid = get_group_id(0);
    int glid = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    int i, j, x = 0;

    __local char *tmp_string;
    event_t event;

    if(l_length < pattern_size){
            return;
    }

    event = async_work_group_copy(tmp_string, string+gid*g_length, g_length, 0);
    wait_group_events(1, &event);
```

Those are some part of my code.

I want to find the matched pattern in the text.

First, initialize all my patterns and string (I read string from text and experimentally use one pattern only) on CPU side.

Second, transfer them to kernel named `kmp`
(parameters `l_length` and `g_length` are the size of string which will be copied to `lid` and `glid` each. In other words, the pieces of the string).

And lastly, I want to copy the divided string to local memory.

But there is a problem. I cannot get any valid result when I copy them using `async_work_group_copy()`.

When I change `__local char*tmp_string` to array, the problem still remains.

What I want to do is

1. divide the string
2. copy them to each thread
3. and compute the matching number.

I wonder what's wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL spec has this:

> The async copy is performed by all work-items in a work-group and this
>   built-in function must therefore be encountered by all work-items in a
>   work-group executing the kernel with the same argument values;
>   otherwise the results are undefined.

so you shouldn't return early for any workitems in a group. Early return is better suited to CPU anyway. If this is GPU, just compute the last overflowing part using augmented/padded input-output buffers.

Otherwise, you can early return whole group(this should work since no workitem hitting any async copy instruction) and do the remaining work on the cpu, unless the device doesn't use any workitems(but a dedicated secret pipeline) for the async copy operation.

Maybe you can enqueue a second kernel(in another queue concurrently) to compute remaining latest items with workgroupsize=remaining_size instead of having extra buffer size or control logic.

---

`tmp_string` needs to be initialized/allocated if you are going to copy something to/from it. So you probably will need the array version of it.

---

`async_work_group_copy` is not a synchronization point so needs a barrier before it to get latest bits of local memory to use for async copy to global.

```
            __kernel void foo(__global int *a, __global int *b)
            {
                int i=get_global_id(0);
                int g=get_group_id(0);
                int l=get_local_id(0);
                int gs=get_local_size(0);
                __local int tmp[256];
                event_t evt=async_work_group_copy(tmp,&a[g*gs],gs,0);
                // compute foobar here in async to copies
                wait_group_events(1,&evt);

                tmp[l]=tmp[l]+3; // compute foobar2 using local memory
                barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

                event_t evt2=async_work_group_copy(&b[g*gs],tmp,gs,0);
                // compute foobar3 here in async to copies
                wait_group_events(1,&evt2);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think I give you some confused information. I didn't return anything before all line in my code executes. The parameter ret is just the name. I returned it to CPU after computing. Anyway I try again!

Comment: @SON.PARK I've meant `return;`. All workitems have to hit workgroup commands.

Comment: I tried and get the proper result. But when I increased the number of threads more than 44, it didn't work well. It found the matched pattern much less than I've intended.(Like, it has to find 443 matched number but only find 1). Do you have any recommend regarding this problem? Thanks!

Comment: use get_local_size(0) instead of g_length